# Trying to make event handlers to drag and drop data between 3 listviews. Works with 2 but not 3. C#

Tags: c#, listview

I have list views A,B and C in my program. I made a list manager object which allows the dragging and dropping of data from each list to the others. It worked fine when I had just lists A and B. But now that I have list C. I can only drag from A to B, B to A, and A to C. I cannot drag from C to A, C to B or B to C. See my List manager class:

```
public class ListViewManager
{
    private ListView sourceListView;
    private ListView destinationListView;

    public ListViewManager(ListView source, ListView destination)
    {
        sourceListView = source;
        destinationListView = destination;

        // Set up drag-and-drop events 
        sourceListView.ItemDrag += SourceListView_ItemDrag;
        destinationListView.DragEnter += DestinationListView_DragEnter;
        destinationListView.DragDrop += DestinationListView_DragDrop;

        // Set up reverse drag-and-drop events
        destinationListView.ItemDrag += DestinationListView_ItemDrag;
        sourceListView.DragEnter += SourceListView_DragEnter;
        sourceListView.DragDrop += SourceListView_DragDrop;
    }

    // Start drag-and-drop operation from sourceListView
    private void SourceListView_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        sourceListView.DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    // Check if the dragged data is of ListViewItem type
    private void SourceListView_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListViewItem)))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    // This method will move from the destination list to the source list
    private void SourceListView_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the dropped item
        ListViewItem draggedItem = (ListViewItem)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem));

        // Remove the item from the destination listView
        destinationListView.Items.Remove(draggedItem);

        // Add the item to the source listView
        sourceListView.Items.Add(draggedItem);
    }

    // Start drag-and-drop operation from destinationListView
    private void DestinationListView_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        destinationListView.DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    // Check if the dragged data is of ListViewItem type
    private void DestinationListView_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListViewItem)))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    // This method will move from the source list to destination list
    private void DestinationListView_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the dropped item
        ListViewItem draggedItem = (ListViewItem)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem));

        // Remove the item from the source listView
        sourceListView.Items.Remove(draggedItem);

        // Add the item to the destination listView
        destinationListView.Items.Add(draggedItem);
    }


}

//in the form i have list managers declared:

private ListViewManager listViewManager1;
private ListViewManager listViewManager2;
private ListViewManager listViewManager3;

//and in the constructor: 

listViewManager1 = new ListViewManager(ListA, ListB);
listViewManager2 = new ListViewManager(ListA, ListC);
listViewManager3 = new ListViewManager(ListB, ListC);

// i have also tried adding more managers

listViewManager4 = new ListViewManager(ListC, ListB);
listViewManager5 = new ListViewManager(ListC, ListA);
```

It seems no matter what i try this same problem persists. i've noticed I can drag the entry and the icon appears when i hover over another list but when i release it doesn't add to the new list and remove from the old one. Any insight?

Comment: You should be using a single method to handle the same event for all `ListViews`. Inside the event handler, you use the `sender` parameter to access the control that raised the event. When you're dropping an item, you would access the source `ListView` via the item's `ListView` property. Your `sourceListView` and `destinationListView` fields are of no value there.